# Кому-то или до кого-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В том же письме в редакцию есть предложение: "В половине одиннадцатого вечера невестка наконец-то дозвонилась друзьям..." И вот мне подумалось: а как правильнее говорить - "дозвониться кому-то" или "дозвониться до кого-то"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что оба варианта можно признать правильными.
Звонить - кому, поэтому дозвониться тоже кому.
Вариант "до кого" появился видимо под влиянием пространственного значения приставки до: дойти до кого. Конечно, такое значение здесь небесспорно, но коли уж сам глагол приобрел такое значение (как писать - кому), совсем исключить вариант "до кого" нельзя. Кузнецов, кстати приводит его как нормативный, а вариант с "кому" даже не упоминает, хотя явно и не исключает.